# Xamarin.Forms & Adal Authentication 4 AcquireTokenAsync

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, adal

I am having trouble authenticating users in `Xamarin.Forms` Portable with `Adal 4` Experimental `(Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.CLients.ActiveDirectory)` . I cannot find how to use `AcquireTokenAsync` because documentation is available only for previous versions of adal and the `AcquireTokenAsync` is now different. Can someone provide a working example here?

Answer (score 0):

There are some extra parameters, yes, but they are just settings. Provided you have your application registered with Azure AD:

```
AuthenticationParameters ap = AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(new Uri(resource+"/api/data/v8.1")).Result;

IPlatformParameters parameters = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto);

AuthenticationResult r = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(ap.Resource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUrl), parameters);
```

If you know the details of the person who will be logging in, you can use:

```
AuthenticationResult r = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(ap.Resource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUrl), parameters, new UserIdentifier(username,UserIdentifierType.RequiredDisplayableId));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Adal is now replaced by msal and some examples for msal can be found for github. Unfortunately i cannot check your solution cause i used something else.

Comment: It is not replaced, it serves a slightly different purpose than ADAL. Microsoft is not shelving ADAL for MSAL. MSAL seems to be the library you'd want to use with Xamarin, now.